# How to use angular validation based on function response true or false in angular 11?

Tags: angular

I have used angular 11 form validation, i have created a function return a response true or false based on condition. If its true validation message should display.

here is my code in ts

```
this.pollAdd = this.fb.group({
      question: ['', Validators.required],
      queChoices: this.fb.array([this.createChoice()]),
      communityId: this.communityId,
      startDate: ['', Validators.required],
      endDate: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

the function which is return the response true or false

```
questionPoll(question){
    this.questionValid=this.totalResponse.some(function(e){
      return e.question == question;
    })
  }
```

I wants to use the true or false condition in formcontrolName question field.kindly suggest the better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it:

```js
this.pollAdd = this.fb.group({
      question: ['', [Validators.required, this.questionPoll()]],
      queChoices: this.fb.array([this.createChoice()]),
      communityId: this.communityId,
      startDate: ['', Validators.required],
      endDate: ['', Validators.required],
    });

questionPoll(){
      return (control: AbstractControl) => {
            if (!control.value) return null;

            if(this.totalResponse.some((e) => {      return e.question == control.value;    })){
                return null
            }else{
                return { required: true }           
            }
        }
  }
```

In this way you transform your function in a custom validator

Comment: i have passed that input value as argument, how to use it in formgroup?

Comment: It's passed automatically by formGroup, you can get the result with control.value. This will be the input that you are changing